# Best way to select huge number of rows from table with EF considering performance

Tags: entity-framework, linq, db2

We need to fetch records from DB2 table; we are using the query shown here, and it is working fine for small number of rows.

Question is: will it work fine for huge number of rows as well, or are any other optimization needed to do so?

```
using (var db = new Db2Context(_connectionString))
{
    var data = db.ProductTable
                 .Where(x => x.productCode == inputCode && 
                             x.USER_SLCT_IN.ToUpper().Equals(userSlctIn.ToUpper()))
                 .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Please include the actual SQL statement and the execution plan.

Comment: Also, when reading large amount of data, use a cursor. Avoid materializing a `List` of records in memory.

Comment: Thanks. I think below also should be fine                             using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                            {
                                if (reader.HasRows)
                                {
                                    while (reader.Read())
                                    {

Comment: @TheImpaler How do you do that when using LINQ and EF?

Comment: I would question why you are reading so many rows. Humans can't process vast amounts, and if you are aggregating the data, you'd be much faster doing that on the database. You may have a valid use case, but I think it would be worth considering it carefully before you proceed, as your question might just go away on its own.

Comment: how many rows do you need to see at once? why not simply implement pagination? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/pagination